# Codename one concurrent animations?

Tags: codenameone

In Codename One, I have a simple chat like UI and want to add messages (labels) using animateLayout. It works fine if there is time between the messages or if the time for animation is small, but when two animations overlap, the second component is not animated. Here is the code I have tried (put this in new codename one project start method):

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    hi.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Button button = new Button("Add");
    Label label = new Label("Status");

    button.addActionListener((actionEvent) -> {
        hi.getContentPane().add("asd");
        hi.getContentPane().animateLayout(3000);
    });

    hi.add(button);
    hi.show();
```

I expected that changing animateLayout to animateLayoutAndWait will solve this, but it did not. I also tried the old workaround:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
    hi.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Button button = new Button("Add");
    Label label = new Label("Status");

    button.addActionListener((actionEvent) -> {
        if(!animateLock) {
            animateLock = true;
            hi.getContentPane().add("asd");
            hi.getContentPane().animateLayout(3000);
            animateLock = false;
        }
    });

    hi.add(button);
    hi.show();
```

where animateLock is a field of the main class. I also tried to wrap the adding in Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {code here}), but it also did not work.
How do I handle concurrent animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [AnimationManager.flushAnimation](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/AnimationManager.html#flushAnimation-java.lang.Runnable-) to post your animation.  This will cause the animation to be run when all other animations are finished.   That should workaround the conflict.

Comment: form.getAnimationManager().flushAnimation() did the job!

Comment: FYI you could have also fixed the code above with `animateLayoutAndWait()`.